# How to loop through csv file in Python/Django

Tags: python, django, csv

I created a `management command` and there I want to download the csv file from ftp and update the database if necessary.

The code that I have is as follows:

```
class Command(BaseCommand):       
    @staticmethod
    def update_database(row):
        code = row['CODE']
        vat_number = row['BTWNR']
        if code != "" and vat_number != "":
            # pdb.set_trace()
            print("Code: {0} --- BTW: {1}").format(code, vat_number)

    def read_file(self):
        path_to_relations_csv_file = "{0}/{1}".format(destination, file_name)
        with open(path_to_relations_csv_file) as csvfile:
            relations_reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile, delimiter=';')    
            for row in relations_reader:    
                self.update_database(row)

    def handle(self, *args, **options):

        # Open ftp connection
        ftp = ftplib.FTP(ftp_host, ftp_username, ftp_password)

        try:
            ftp.cwd(source)  # Goes to remote folder where the relations file is
            os.chdir(destination)  # Goes to local folder where the relations file will be downloaded
            print("Switched to the directory successful. Current directory: {}".format(destination))
        except OSError:
            pass
        except ftplib.error_perm:
            print("Error: could not change to {0}".format(source))
            sys.exit("Ending Application")

        try:
            # Get the file
            relations = open(file_name, "wb")  # Opens the remote file
            ftp.retrbinary('RETR {0}'.format(file_name), relations.write)  # Writes to the local file
            print("File {0} downloaded successfully.".format(file_name))

            relations.close()  # Closes the local file
            print("Local file closed.")
            ftp.quit()  # Closes the ftp connection
            print("FTP Connection quited.")

            try:
                self.read_file()
            except:
                print("Error: Unable to read the file.")
        except:
            print("Error: File {0} could not be downloaded.".format(file_name))
```

But in `read_file` method the for loop gives me the error. If I place `pdb.set_trace()`before for loop I can see that `relations_reader` is `<csv.DictReader object at 0x10e67a6a0>`, thus it seems ok, but if I try to loop over it it goes to the `except` and it execute `print("Error: Unable to read the file.")`

The path are correct.

If the same code is executed as a separated file with `python file_name.py` and not as command with `python manage.py file_name` everything works fine.

Any idea what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried adding `"rb"` to your `open` call?

Comment: @The_Cthulhu_Kid Yes. But the same error.

Comment: Well, why don't you print more? Like exact error?

Comment: @Adelin I get the error as follows: `iterator should return strings, not bytes (did you open the file in text mode?)`

Comment: `open(path_to_relations_csv_file, "rt", encoding='utf-8') as csvfile:`

Comment: The utf-8 is default encoding, but I used `ISO-8859-1` and it worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `iterator should return strings, not bytes (did you open the file in text mode?)` means you need to open the CSV in other ways, than the way you do.

To solve, change the opening mode, and the encoding, to the one it fits your csv file

`open(path_to_relations_csv_file, "rt", encoding='utf-8') as csvfile:`